# Help with htaccess redirect for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm using this code to redirect all subdomains to the subdomain folder.
For example test.site.com => site.com/test.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.site\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/%1 [L]
```

When I visit test.site.com it automatically redirects to the folder test/.I want to stay at the domain test.site.com and show the contents of test/ folder without redirecting to the actuall folder.Thanks.

Comment: That's not possible. In mod_rewrite if HOST_NAME is changing then it has to be an external redirect and the URL in browser will change to show the new HOST_NAME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do achive that with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.site\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```